# How do I convert my GPS NEMA sentences to a string using an Arduino?

Tags: c++, string, gps, arduino

I am attempting to parse information from a GPS module using an Arduino Uno. My thought was to convert the NEMA sentences to strings, then use a simple code to split the comma separated text into groups. Once that is accomplished I can then display certain portions of those groups to a screen.

Is this possible? I have included my very simple code below. Please keep in mind I am a beginner when it comes to code.

```
int rxPin = 0;                    // RX PIN 
int txPin = 1;                    // TX TX
String text = Serial.read();
String message = text;
int commaPostion;

void setup() {
   pinMode(rxPin, INPUT);
   pinMode(txPin, OUTPUT);
   Serial.begin(4800);
   Serial.println(message);
   do{
     commaPosition = message.indexof(',');
     if(commaPosition != -1)
     {
       Serial.println(message.substring(0,commaPosition));
       message = message.substring(commaPosition+1, message.length());
     }
     else
     { //here after last comma is found
         if(message.length() > 0)
             Serial.println(message);
     }
     while(commaPosition >=0);
     {
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: Remove all references to the pins 0 and 1, the arduino chip "knows" that these pins are the Rx/Tx pins for serial comm, so no pinMode() statements are needed.

Answer (score 0):

In programming, laziness is a virtue. Why reinvent the wheel, right?

Check out the [TinyGPS](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygps/) library designed to do exactly what you're trying to accomplish.